# Do not include media in permalink structure Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, media, permalinks

Is there a way to exclude all uploaded media from the wordpress permalink sturcture? Currently wordpress adds all media (images, documents, etc) by default in the permalink structure. However, when uploading a logo with the name logo.png and making a new page in the permalink structure with the same name 'logo', wordpress OR doesn't get it, OR shows a 404 OR shows the image. I do not want my images to have a permalink so I want to exclude them. Any suggestions?

Comment: using the wordpress seo plugin by Yoast! gives you the ability to turn off what you need.. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-seo/